# Why did xamarin stop supporting calabash

Tags: ruby, cucumber, calabash, calabash-android, calabash-ios

Right now I am using calabash for my testing if xamarin stop further development, What is the future of calabash? Is it time to move to a different framework like Appium or is someone gonna keep calabash development alive? Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

After a quick search, I believe this should clear things up a bit:

"While the Calabash framework will not receive new features, we will continue to support running Calabash tests in both Xamarin Test Cloud and Mobile Center Test, including for the upcoming iOS 11 and Android O releases. Existing Calabash tests will continue to run in Test Cloud until breaking changes are introduced in future OS versions, at which point existing tests may begin to fail."

You can find out more [here](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/93584/question-about-calabash-announcement)

Seems they are going for a more native approach, Espresso and XCUITest, as well as Appium.